# C# says my namespace causes a NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, iis

So I got the dreaded "yellow screen of death"(? that's what the .NET guys called it) with the error message:

`[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]`

OK, that's fine, I can understand that, but the error references a line of code which reads:

```
<namespace1>.<namespace2>.XMLDohickey responseXML = 
                                  new <namespace1>.<namespace2>.XMLDohickey();
```

(names obscured to protect the innocent (: ).

I can easily see how the line after, `Session[<value>].ToString();`, could cause this error, but I don't understand how the error could be caused by the line it claims to be caused by.

So, is it that C# is telling me the wrong line number, or can a namespace actually be null?

As a side note -- this seems to work fine locally, on my company's DEV and QA servers, but it seems like it failed on our client's QA server...

### EDIT

---

So... here's the deal.

Apparently, when .NET crashes, sometimes it returns the last successful line called instead of the line which actually held the error. In this case, the `Session[<value>]` was null (Why? No idea. that "Should never happen").

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A namespace can never be null, it will never generate any runtime errors of any kind (in the way you are describing it). So your null reference is probably in Session[key].ToString(), or the constructor of XMLDoHickey. I would consider checking if the value in the session state exists before calling a method on it.

Comment: See question for more specifics

Answer (score 5):

Are you sure the exception doesn't come from inside the XMLDohickey constructor?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately. Here's the constructor: `_xml = new XmlDocument();`

Comment: @cwallenpoole, what about the fields inside, are any of them constructed inline?

Answer (score 4):

You need to force a recompilation and probably also clear the temporary internet files.

THere are often mismatches in the line numbers and the actual instruction causing the exception when source and binaries get out of sync and this must be the case here since namespaces surely dont cause null reference  exceptions :)